# Start bootstrap-datepicker from current month

Tags: datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [bootstrap-datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox). Following are the steps to reproduce my issue

- Go to Demo [here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)
- Click on textbox at the bottom to open calendar
- Use previous arrow to navigate away from current month (say to January)
- Click outside (without selecting any date)
- Click textbox again to open calendar

Actual: You'll notice last selected month is displayed (January in this case)

Expected: I need calendar to always start from current Month.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (events) http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html is seems the picker is will be hide / shown when not visible but not reset.

Use the shown or hide event to set the [startView](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#startview) to the current month.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, to resolve this:
 Write a 'hide' event for the datepicker as-

```
$("#startdate").datepicker({
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: true,
    }).on('hide', function (selected) {
    $('#startdate').datepicker("setDate",new Date());
  });
```